# Error while printing pdf file in JAVA using Runtime.getRuntime()

Tags: java, pdf, printing

There was an older code which use to work earlier but is not working anymore. It used to print a pdf file. The code is given below.

I tried to find out what makes the code run earlier because I feel the earlier code shouldn't work. But as I was told that it was working fine and I did check the git history for the same. Nothing has changed in the past 10 years.

The issue is not with the file, its present on the path.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String printCommand = "lp -d PRINTER_NAME -n ";     
        int copies = 2;
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(printCommand + copies + " " + "FILE_NAME.pdf");       
    }

}
```

I am getting below error on executing this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "lp": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.utd.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: seems like that's an OS-specific call for printing.  What OS are you running this in?

Comment: I tried this on both linux and windows but the same error. And I think it is OS specific and this command for Linux only.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ProcessBuilder to run the command rather than executing from the runtime:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("lp", "-d", "PRINTER_NAME", "-n", "2", PATH_TO_FILE);
pb.directory(new File("C:/"));
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I forgot to mention that I have tried this as a solution but it didn't help.

Comment: Is the directory that the file is in part of the PATH environment variable?  Otherwise I would think you need to specify the entire, full path to the file as part of the command.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Josh. Yeah the paths are correct. I tried with full path, absolute paths etc. and all combinations but dint help.